# HTML encode UTF-8 string gets mangled into latin1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rack

I'm parsing my nginx logs, and I want to discover some details from the HTTP_REFERER string, for example, the query string used to find the web site. One user typed in "México" which gets encoded in the log as "query=M%E9xico".

Passing this through `Rack::Utils.parse_query('query=M%E9xico')` you get a hash, `{"query" => "M?xico"}`

When you to stuff "M?exico" into Postgres (but not the more forgiving SQLite), it pukes because the string isn't proper UTF-8. Looking at http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Utils.html#M000324, unescape is packing a hex string.

How can I convert the string back to UTF-8, or can I get parse_query to return UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: The information is already broken in the log: %E9 shows it isn't UTF-8. You can't convert it without making assumptions about what the initial character set was.

Answer (score 1):

unescape will decode the URL encoding:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.unescape('query=M%E9xico'))
```

Or

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(Utils.unescape('query=M%E9xico'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here happens well before you get ahold of the data.  You need to fix the problem upstream if you can, and if you can't then my suggestion is find out the encoding and convert it on input or using conversion libraries in Ruby (iconv for example).

The problem is not in PostgreSQL, though.